# How to eliminate period of unresponsiveness when checking for disconnected share drive in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, network-drive

I have a database that has a lot of stored data in a shared drive (another database and stored pictures to look up). To make sure that this data is present before I try to access it, I run a small sub to check if it is connected and will allow the user to retry the connection again if it failed:

```
 Public Sub CheckConnection()

 Dim Ans As Long
 On Error GoTo NotConnected
 ReDo:

 If Dir("<Filepath>", vbDirectory) <> "" Then Exit Sub

 NotConnected:
 Ans = MsgBox("Access can't find the share drive! Please check your connection to the Share Drive!" & vbNewLine & _
 "If you have reconnected to the sharedirve, click ""Retry"". Otherwise click ""Cancel"" to close the database.", vbRetryCancel, "Connection Error")

 Select Case Ans
     Case 2 'Cancel
         DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll
     Case Else
         Resume ReDo
 End Select
 End Sub
```

The issue with this is that the first time (and only the first time) this code runs and fails, Access grays out and says that it is not responding for 10-20 seconds before the msgbox pops up. Once this happens, and subsequent failures are immediate causing the msgbox to pop up again as quickly as you can click retry. I want to know how to eliminate that initial time out of Access and immediately let the user see the msgbox.

I have also tried the following code and it yielded the same results:

```
 Dim fso As Object
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Select Case fso.FolderExists(fso.GetParentFolderName(<Filepath>))
     Case True
         Exit sub
     Case False
 End Select

 Ans = MsgBox("Access can't find the share drive! Please check your connection to the Share Drive!" & vbNewLine & _
 "If you have reconnected to the sharedirve, click ""Retry"". Otherwise click ""Cancel"" to close the database.", vbRetryCancel, "Connection Error")

 Select Case Ans
     Case 2 'Cancel
         DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll
     Case Else
         Resume ReDo
 End Select
```

Comment: Is the path to a mapped drive e.g `Z:\...` or a UNC path like `\\server\folder...` ?

Comment: Hey Tim, the path is UNC since I know not all users using the shared drive mapped it under the same name.